# How to pass custom class in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-json

I'm using Volley GET method and I successfully  got response.Now i try to deserialize response and then i try to pass custom class in another activity

```
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    mShowDialog();
    String url = "************";
    UTF8VolleySupport sr = new UTF8VolleySupport(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response + "mm");
            hideDialog(pDialog);
            TrainsMainClass trainsMainClass;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String errorcode = jsonObject.getString("errorcode");
                if (errorcode.equals("500")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (jsonObject.has("data")) {
                    trainsMainClass = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("data"), TrainsMainClass.class);
                    if (trainsMainClass != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainsActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putSerializable("trainsMainClass", trainsMainClass);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            hideDialog(pDialog);
            NetworkResponse errorRes = error.networkResponse;
            String stringData = "";
            if (errorRes != null && errorRes.data != null) {
                try {
                    stringData = new String(errorRes.data, "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e("Error", stringData);
        }
    });

    sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(sr);
```

---

```
public class TrainsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TrainsMainClass trainsMainClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trains);
    trainsMainClass = new TrainsMainClass();
    if (getIntent() != null) {
        trainsMainClass = (TrainsMainClass) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("trainsMainClass");
        if (trainsMainClass != null)
            Log.e("trainsMainClass", trainsMainClass + "");

    }
}
}
```

---

```
public class TrainsMainClass implements Serializable{
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TrainsMainClass{" +
            "trainDeparture=" + trainDeparture +
            ", trainReturn=" + trainReturn +
            '}';
}

@SerializedName("departure")
private Timetable trainDeparture;

@SerializedName("return")
private Timetable trainReturn;

}
```

This is my source,but when I run my app i have exception.
How i can solve my problem?

```
`Parcelable` encountered `IOException` writing serializable object
```

Comment: Why not just pass the jsonResponse string in intent which can be parsed later in the new activity that you are starting!

Comment: you can use public static className objectname;

Comment: try after adding default constructor to your class "public TrainsMainClass () {}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass the jsonResponse string in intent which can be parsed later in the new activity that you are starting!

```
intent.putExtraString("jsonResp", jsonObject.getString("data"));
startActivity(intent);
```

& in your other activity, you can parse the response into object using GSON

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trains);
        trainsMainClass = new TrainsMainClass();
        if (getIntent() != null) {
        String response = getIntent().getExtraString("jsonResp");
        if(response !=null){
            trainsMainClass = gson.fromJson(, TrainsMainClass.class);
                Log.e("trainsMainClass", trainsMainClass + "");

        }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the JSON string can potentially be pretty large, AFAIK current limitation for the size of the data that you can transfer with an Intent is around 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid passing large amounts of data between Activities, there's an upper limit on the size of data that can be passed with an `Intent`. Alternatively, what I'd suggest to do is:

1. Read the data in the first `Activity`, parse it and store either in DB, or in an in-memory storage. Make sure there's a meaningful ID field in your data.
2. Pass the ID (which will probably be either `int`, `long` or `String`) with the `Intent` to the second `Activity`.
3. In second `Activity`, get the data by ID from the storage.

This solution will scale well for any amount of data you're passing between Activities, and additionally, given that you'll be keeping your data in memory, you won't be paying the cost of serializing and deserializing the data from the `Intent`.